# How align external swf into a specific MovieClip?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, external

i am new here.i have a problem, i am trying to import external swf into a Movieclip but when i do it...my swf isn´t align.i don´t know why.

the code that i use is:

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("prod.swf"); 
var loader:Loader = new Loader(); 
loader.load(request); 
addChild(loader);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `contentLoaderInfo` and `Event.COMPLETE` like so,

```
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("prod.swf"); 
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSWFLoad);
loader.load(request); 
addChild(loader);

function onSWFLoad(e:Event):void
{
    var loadedSWF:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target.content);

    //Now you can access and set MovieClip's properties like width, height, position etc

    someMovieClip.addChild(loadedSWF);

    loadedSWF.x = 100; //x Position
    loadedSWF.y = 100; //y Position

}
```